# Solving race condition in rest api calls

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have an `REST API` which is ment to collect information about `urls` used by 3rd party applications. There is a sniffer installed which is looking for HTTP request and then call the `API` providing information about urls and headers used.

I would like to store URLs as unique as possible so each search for user:

```
http://localhost/users/49a95b87-083e-475b-9278-bade6f24413b
http://localhost/users/508f2a55-fe5b-4b83-b853-7e829dd366b8
http://localhost/users/af48be64-ad48-4867-ac06-984ce064dbeb
```

would be stored as one entry to database (uuid is not important here so it is oke that only last or first will stay). Algorithm to do so is like that:

> 1. Get request
> 2. Check if database contains similiar url
> 3. If database return no findings store url to database

Where controller is:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_API')")
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/webapp")
    public synchronized ResponseEntity<Status> getWebApp(@RequestBody ServiceDiscovery req) throws InterruptedException {
        return webAppService.processWebAppRequest(req.getWebApp());
    }
```

service method: `webAppService.processWebAppRequest`

```
private final static String UUID_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}";
    private final static String SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN = "[0-9]{19}";
    private final static String MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN = "[0-9]{9}";
    private final static String MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN = "[0-9]{11}";

    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Status> processScanWebAppRequest(ServiceDiscovery serviceDiscovery){
        try {
            Optional<WebApp> wa = checkRegexes(serviceDiscovery.getUrl());
            if (wa.isPresent()){
                updateExistingWebApplication(serviceDiscovery, wa.get());
            } else {
                saveNewWebApplication(serviceDiscovery);
            }
        } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Status>(new Status("Processing error"), HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        } 
        return new ResponseEntity<Status>(new Status("OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    //Checkregex function which return Optional.empty it looks for regex in string and then replace finding with regex itself so it can be used in JPA query
    private Optional<WebApp> checkRegexes(String url) {
        String urlToLookFor = url.replaceAll(UUID_PATTERN,UUID_PATTERN);
        urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN,SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN);
        urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN,MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN);
        urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN,MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN);

        return waRepository.getWebAppByRegex(urlToLookFor+"$");
    }
    //JPA check for 
    @Query(value="select * from webapp wa where wa.url ~ :url", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<WebApp> getWebAppByRegex(@Param("url") String url);
```

And everything works good while I test it. But on the production environment I got periodically huge amount of requests (once a day ~5k requests in few seconds) where there are plenty of UUIDs for the same endpoint sent which are being processed parallel so when `checkRegexes` is being done there is no finding but 1 second later there are 5.

To avoid this I tried to set API to `synchronized` but no success. Is there anyway to make it work without changes to the client?

example output using query is:

```
db=# select inserted, url from webapp where url ~ 'https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$' order by inserted;
      inserted       |                                        url
---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/cd1da115-a2c1-4722-a381-6d524cbf5c95
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/6b9b2c76-f416-4c8c-a0b0-01d29e976c03
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/0f197568-0d2f-405d-8468-3bbea8b3a8ef
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/32e02581-02b4-4a99-9121-1592b0a67566
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/f1bbb4cf-1336-45ec-814f-77ecb9736c47
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/6b0969a1-cfd7-4cda-9041-14229ddb3c6f
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/1fa4e464-aae6-472e-9a4c-cf4c7d6b4e0f
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/a25cbb9c-49c8-4603-aeb6-68d5a065c58e
 2019-10-30 10:55:00 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/e9be9949-f866-4765-9d38-582193dd1839
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/ad46db32-82dd-4c8e-9e77-a67e59dfca9a
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/fed07e4a-42e4-44e3-b932-9d0e01a5b535
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/747ff6df-dea5-48db-a15b-b7f43bc48ecf
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/4b6341ad-2584-427d-898a-f24d3623eb32
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/1e75c8bb-fb27-4183-a993-6763fa796e79
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/72b19740-7f61-4a32-88f9-0f7196d47853
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/6c21da91-56eb-498b-91bd-4895be3cfdcc
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/a7d3dc5c-c5de-4fc4-9c56-9eefe7a67d80
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/b9658963-c1f5-45da-b78d-240bc7b2a225
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/e8be9c46-e7d0-4642-9c7b-981663aa552e
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/74886e61-150d-4f35-8af0-c911cfdbf009
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/175840ab-9f4c-43b7-a684-1adeb884af71
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/7655bf87-1f34-4a38-9ad0-11c5c1ddbb6b
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/34406b3d-319d-4ca4-9ca2-d53c104ad703
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/15f40dc6-5852-4f9f-9017-87b20dd326f1
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/de5caa58-cb7b-4dac-9b87-b6f4460072f3
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/b601b86b-ba8e-4768-b013-12d12f74362b
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/a64fd22b-f144-4b70-b3bb-86ee0e7a47c6
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/87672dac-ce7d-4a03-acfc-e694d229c4fe
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/ea6db1e8-461b-459a-b5d0-2f4aec872cdd
 2019-10-30 11:10:43 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/d4b7cd3c-68bd-42e4-99d0-0f5043428080
 2019-10-30 11:24:11 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/4dfd42cc-4029-46dc-8867-adafac249345
 2019-10-30 11:24:11 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/2be89a7a-cf26-4163-bd49-0549bba24cd0
 2019-10-30 11:24:11 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/3d1f3f34-a11d-4f8a-b5d5-7d8fc58e49f0
 2019-10-30 11:24:11 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/db1ec2c3-5571-4db0-a3fe-6e12a4b1ae46
 2019-10-30 11:24:11 | https://api-gateway.intra.com/users/75f964aa-db57-43d3-a424-99345c8c9997
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to synchronize access to DB. So `select`,`save` and `update` operations should be in synchronized block. But it will reduce concurrency to single thread and performance degradation will be enormous. So there is some trick you could use to synchronize the DB access but save the performance at some rate.

You could synchronize DB access by hash of the mormilized url .
I use `url_hash %10000` to limit number of lock objects.
Of course it will affect performance but it will be in 10000 better then simple synchronization.

Have a look at the code:

```
private final static String UUID_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}";
private final static String SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN = "[0-9]{19}";
private final static String MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN = "[0-9]{9}";
private final static String MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN = "[0-9]{11}";

private final Map<Integer, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Status> processScanWebAppRequest(ServiceDiscovery serviceDiscovery){
    try {
        String urlToLookFor = normalizeUrl(serviceDiscovery.getUrl());
        int lockHash = urlToLookFor.hashCode() % 10000;
        synchronized (locks.computeIfAbsent(lockHash, integer -> new Object())) {
            Optional<WebApp> wa = checkRegexes(urlToLookFor);
            if (wa.isPresent()){
                updateExistingWebApplication(serviceDiscovery, wa.get());
            } else {
                saveNewWebApplication(serviceDiscovery);
            }
        }
    } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Status>(new Status("Processing error"), HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Status>(new Status("OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
}

private String normalizeUrl(String url) {
    String urlToLookFor = url.replaceAll(UUID_PATTERN,UUID_PATTERN);
    urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN,SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN);
    urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN,MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN);
    urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN,MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN);
    return urlToLookFor;
}

private Optional<WebApp> checkRegexes(String url) {
    return waRepository.getWebAppByRegex(urlToLookFor+"$");
}
```

Comment: apparently it dit not work while I can see more and more duplicated rows :( Dou You think maybe pessimistic locking both on webapp.save and webapp.getWebAppByRegex would work in this scenario?

Comment: It has to work. Could you check that duplicates have the same `hash` and `normalizeUrl(String url)` returns same value for the duplicated urls.

Comment: I have found the issue:
`checkRegexes(serviceDiscovery.getUrl());` has to be replaced with `checkRegexes(urlToLookFor);`. I have fixed the answer, have a look please.

Comment: Hash is the same, when I do inspect more carefully I have started storing also time of insertion and I can see that multiple URLs are stored in exacly same time (aprox to ms)

Comment: Did you replace `checkRegexes(serviceDiscovery.getUrl());` with `checkRegexes(urlToLookFor);` ?

Comment: Can you provide examples of the duplicated urls? 
Is it possible that you have two application instances?

Comment: Could you check that your query "select * from webapp wa where wa.url ~ :url" returns duplicated urls ? I think the issue in this query.

Comment: From your example we can see that duplicates were added at `2019-10-30 10:55:00` and `2019-10-30 11:24:11`. So there is no race conditions it is duplicate validation issue. It is impossible has a race condition for 30 minutes.  Is't it? You need to check the duplicate detection approach. Can you sequentially add duplicated urls by hands? (it will show you if your duplication check works, but as I see from your urls example it doesn't)