# Order of processing REST API calls

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a strage(for me) question to ask. I have created synchronized `Service` which is called by `Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class WebAppApiController {
    private final WebAppService webApService;
    @Autowired
    WebAppApiController(WebAppService webApService){
        this.webApService= webApService;

    }
    @Transactional
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_API')")
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/webapp/{projectId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Status> getWebApp(@PathVariable(value = "projectId") Long id, @RequestBody WebAppRequestModel req) {
        return webApService.processWebAppRequest(id, req);
    }
}
```

`Service` layer is just checking if there is no duplicate in request and store it in database. Because client which is using this endpoint is making MANY requests continously it happened that before one request was validated agnist duplicate other the same was put in database - that is why I am trying to do synchronized block.

```
@Service
public class WebAppService {
    private final static String UUID_PATTERN_TO = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}";
    private final WebAppRepository waRepository;
    @Autowired
    public WebAppService(WebAppRepository waRepository){
        this.waRepository= waRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Status> processScanWebAppRequest(Long id, WebAppScanModel webAppScanModel){
        try{
            synchronized (this){
                Optional<WebApp> webApp=verifyForDuplicates(webAppScanModel);
                if(!webApp.isPresent()){
                    WebApp webApp=new WebApp(webAppScanModel.getUrl())
                    webApp=waRepository.save(webApp);
                    processpropertiesOfWebApp(webApp);
                    return new ResonseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
                }
                return new ResonseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException ex){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException ex){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        }
    }
}
Optional<WebApp> verifyForDuplicates(WebAppScanModel webAppScanModel){
    return waRepository.getWebAppByRegex(webAppScanModel.getUrl().replaceAll(UUID_PATTERN_TO,UUID_PATTERN_TO)+"$");
}
```

And JPA method:

```
@Query(value="select * from webapp wa where wa.url ~ :url", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<WebApp> getWebAppByRegex(@Param("url") String url);
```

`processpropertiesOfWebApp` method is doing further processing for given webapp which at this point should be unique.

Intended behaviour is:
when client post request contains multiple urls like:

```
https://testdomain.com/user/7e1c44e4-821b-4d05-bdc3-ebd43dfeae5f
https://testdomain.com/user/d398316e-fd60-45a3-b036-6d55049b44d8
https://testdomain.com/user/c604b551-101f-44c4-9eeb-d9adca2b2fe9
```

Only first one will be stored within database but at this moment this is not what is happening. Select from my database:

```
select inserted,url from webapp where url ~ 'https://testdomain.com/users/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$';
2019-11-07 08:53:05 | https://testdomain.com/users/d398316e-fd60-45a3-b036-6d55049b44d8
2019-11-07 08:53:05 | https://testdomain.com/users/d398316e-fd60-45a3-b036-6d55049b44d8
2019-11-07 08:53:05 | https://testdomain.com/users/d398316e-fd60-45a3-b036-6d55049b44d8 
(3 rows)
```

I will try to add `unique` constraint on `url` column but I can't imagine this will solve the problem while when `UUID` changes new `url` will be `unique`

Could anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Question is related with [the one I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516619/solving-race-condition-in-rest-api-calls/58517204?noredirect=1#comment103599578_58517204) but not found proper solution, so I simplified my method but still no success

Comment: I have doubt on **verifyForDuplicates(webAppScanModel)**; did you check with console statement if its working fine

Comment: When I test it using postman it works. I even created jmeter scenario to make more then 100 request in a second and it still works, but when client is using the same method it produced unexpected results

Comment: This will only work with slowing down your request handling and will only work with a single in stance of the application. As soon as you deploy 2 instances it will break. The only 100% save way is by a constraint on the DB. You probably want a CHECK constraint with a pattern of the liks.

Comment: I have only single instance of application and I have no plans to expand it. I can't imagine how pattern should look like today it is /users/uuid tommorow will be /product/uuid and day after tomorrow /user/uuid/product/uuid